# Force 16:9 from 4:3, Intel graphics

Tags: intel-graphics

Is there a way to force 4:3 screen resolution/scale to 16:9? I wanna be able to run 1024x768 in a 16:9 scale(fullscreen) on my notebook. So far its only 1366x768 that is scaling to 16:9.

I have a Intel® Sandybridge Mobile graphic card. Tried to use CompizConfig with no luck.
I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 with GNOME desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Graphic card is what controls the screen resolution, not CompizConfig. ComplizConfig only is able to access to "already configurated installation".  So it sounds like you need to update your graphic card driver as Intel has just released the driver updates specifically for Ubuntu last summer.  https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.2-linux